# Alfresco 7.1 Does not extract text from PDF/A of large files

Tags: pdf, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've been trying to get Alfresco to extract texts from PDF/A files larger than 25 MB and I haven't been successful.
I've read countless pages of documentation, installed different versions on different operating systems.
I tested several recommended settings, removed all the limits I could find.
All of this without success.

At the moment I'm using:

- Alfresco version **7.1**
- Search Services **2.0.2**
- Ubuntu **20.04**
  (compatible version according to documentation).
- Installation was done through **Ansible**. Following all the documentation.

Alfresco can extract text from PDF files smaller than 25MB, but none larger than that. The logs do not return any problems regarding this.

I know this from the logs, here 2 PDFs of different sizes were sent. But only one extracted the text:
[image]

**Goal**: Be able to search for terms that exist in PDF/A files larger than 25MB.

Some settings I've tried:

```
### Time out configured for all extractor and all mimetypes
content.metadataExtracter.default.timeoutMs=3600000

### Maximum size of a document to process - configured for PdfBoxMetadataExtracter , pdf files
content.metadataExtracter.pdf.maxDocumentSizeMB=900

### Maximum number of concurrent extractions - configured for PdfBoxMetadataExtracter , pdf files
content.metadataExtracter.pdf.maxConcurrentExtractionsCount=15


content.transformer.default.timeoutMs=3600000
content.transformer.default.txt.*.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.JodConverter.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.JodConverter.extensions.doc.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.JodConverter.extensions.doc.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes.use.asyncRule=1073741824
content.transformer.default.extensions.pdf.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes.use.index=1073741824
content.transformer.TikaAuto.timeoutMs.use.index=3600000
content.transformer.default.extensions.doc.txt.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.TikaAuto.timeoutMs=3600000
content.transformer.default.extensions.pdf.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.default.extensions.pdf.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes.use.webpreview=1073741824
content.transformer.PdfBox.extensions.pdf.txt.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
content.transformer.TikaAuto.extensions.pdf.txt.maxSourceSizeKBytes=1073741824
```

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://docs.alfresco.com/transform-service/1.4/config/extend/):

```
export TRANSFORMER_ROUTES_ADDITIONAL_custom="/etc/opt/alfresco/content-services/classpath/alfresco/extension/transform/pipelines/custom-pipeline-file.json"
```

And I created the file **custom-pipeline-file.json** with the most varied configurations, here are some that I tried:

```
{
  "overrideSupported": [
    {
      "maxSourceSizeBytes": 1073741824
    }
  ]
}
```

.

```
{
  "transformers": [
    {
      "transformerName": "tika",
      "supportedSourceAndTargetList": [
        {"sourceMediaType": "application/pdf", "maxSourceSizeBytes": 1073741824, "targetMediaType": "text/plain" },
        {"sourceMediaType": "application/pdf", "priority": 40, "targetMediaType": "text/plain" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And after the changes, I have restarted the service using the commands below:

```
sudo service alfresco-content restart
sudo service alfresco-search restart
sudo service alfresco-tengine-aio restart
```

After digging deeper into this I got a configuration in the file I created **custom-pipeline-file.json** which gave a different result. Here's the configuration:

```
{
     "transformers": [
        {
            "transformerName": "PdfBox",
            "supportedSourceAndTargetList": [
                 {"sourceMediaType": "application/pdf", "maxSourceSizeBytes": 1073741824, "targetMediaType": "text/plain"}
            ],
            "transformOptions": [
                "pdfboxOptions"
            ]
        }]
}
```

And I get the error below in the logs:

```
2022-10-25 02:44:40.172 ERROR 41834 --- [nio-8090-exec-7] o.a.transformer.TransformController      : No transforms were able to handle the request

org.alfresco.transform.exceptions.TransformException: No transforms were able to handle the request
    at org.alfresco.transformer.AbstractTransformerController.getTransformerName(AbstractTransformerController.java:444) ~[alfresco-transformer-base-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.alfresco.transformer.AbstractTransformerController.getTransformerName(AbstractTransformerController.java:421) ~[alfresco-transformer-base-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.alfresco.transformer.AbstractTransformerController.transform(AbstractTransformerController.java:172) ~[alfresco-transformer-base-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

I will really appreciate it if someone can give me a way to solve this, as I've been trying for weeks.